# Passing a Scala function to a Java 8 method

Tags: functional-programming, scala, functions, higher-order-functions, java8

The following Scala code works and can be passed to a Java method expecting a function.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?  Here's my first pass:

```
val plusOne = new java.util.function.Function[Int,Int] {
  override def apply(t:Int):Int = t + 1

  override def andThen[V](after:function.Function[_ >: Int, _ <: V]):
    function.Function[Int, V] = ???

  override def compose[V](before:function.Function[_ >: V, _ <: Int]):
    function.Function[V, Int] = ???
}
```

Here's my second pass - it uses a generic wrapper for the Java-8 Function interface to make the Scala syntax simpler:

```
// Note: Function1 is Scala's functional interface,
// Function (without the 1) is Java 8's.
case class JavaFunction1[U,V](f:Function1[U,V]) extends Function[U,V] {
  override def apply(t: U): V = f(t)
  override def compose[T](before:Function[_ >: T, _ <: U]):
    Function[T, V] = ???
  override def andThen[W](after:Function[_ >: V, _ <: W]):
    Function[U, W] = ???
}

val plusOne = JavaFunction1((x:Int) => x + 1)
val minusOne = JavaFunction1((x:Int) => x - 1)
```

Can we do better?

As a follow-up, is there any chance that Scala will someday use the invoke-dynamic op-code as Java 8 does for its first-class function application?  Will that make everything magically work, or will there still need to be a syntactic conversion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make the conversion implicit:

```
implicit def toJavaFunction[U, V](f:Function1[U,V]): Function[U, V] = new Function[U, V] {
  override def apply(t: U): V = f(t)

  override def compose[T](before:Function[_ >: T, _ <: U]):
    Function[T, V] = toJavaFunction(f.compose(x => before.apply(x)))

  override def andThen[W](after:Function[_ >: V, _ <: W]):
    Function[U, W] = toJavaFunction(f.andThen(x => after.apply(x)))
}

implicit def fromJavaFunction[U, V](f:Function[U,V]): Function1[U, V] = f.apply
```

You shouldn't actually need to override `compose` and `andThen`, but maybe Scala compiler doesn't know about Java 8 default interface methods yet. (EDIT: it should work in 2.10.3.)

Also, you should be able to assign Scala lambdas (i.e. `x => ...`) to `Function` and any other SAM types in Scala 2.11, and Java 8 lambdas to `Function1`. (EDIT: this actually got added in Scala 2.12, not 2.11.)

Comment: `you should be able to assign Scala lambdas` - This means that, in Scala 2.11, a Scala function can be passed as an argument for a Java8 Lambda?

Comment: Whether it can be passes as an _argument_ depends on the lambda's type; if it's e.g. `java.util.function.Consumer[scala.Function1[Integer, String]]` then it can be done before 2.11 too.